# Php Post FATAL EXCEPTION -- Async and permission included

Tags: android, android-asynctask

The code below keeps giving errors. I've taken this code from [here](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/) and it seems ok. The problem is i've checked every topic in stackoverflow about errors. Done adding internet permissons and internet state permissions. Also used AsyncTask class correctly. i'll add the whole error here. When i press the button these errors pop up:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText value;
private Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (value.getText().toString().length() < 1) {

        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());
    }


}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://somewebsite.com/receiver.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

}
```

}

***and error here***

```
11-29 07:21:11.958    1856-1869/com.example.nova.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.nova.myapplication, PID: 1856
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=erdemsimsek.info/deneme.php
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.example.nova.myapplication.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.postData(MainActivity.java:81)
        at com.example.nova.myapplication.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
        at com.example.nova.myapplication.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

***MANIFEST FILE:***

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nova.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>s
```

Comment: Post your android manafest please

Comment: Posted, also see [link](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/)

Comment: Please again read error log which identify your problem : Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nova.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

now do,

```
String valueIWantToSend;

 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (value.getText().toString().length() < 1) {

        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
      valueIWantToSend = value.getText().toString();
      new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }



@Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData();
        return null;
    }




public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://somewebsite.com/receiver.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

Comment: after pressing the button i'm getting errors. i think its not about manifest file. uploaded errors

Comment: Changed but still getting the exact same errors. Is there any way that you can create a xxx.com/get.php site for test? maybe its about web site's existence.

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nova.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Try moving the permissions 'outside' the application tags

Comment: after pressing the button i'm getting errors. i think its not about manifest file. uploaded errors